# Solving Trigonometric Equations involving the sum of two cubes

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\sin^3 \theta + \cos^3 \theta}{1 - 2\cos^2 \theta} = \frac{\sec \theta -\sin \theta}{\tan\theta + 1}$$

This is a homework problem we received the first week of class. It's due tomorrow morning so suffice to say, I won't get an answer in time. However, I would really like to understand as much as possible to avoid getting lost in class.

The hint the professor provided said to work from the left side and use the sum of two cubes identity ($a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) $) for the numerator.

I have worked for hours on this and not even the tutor knew what to do. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Trig identites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) are your friends.

Comment: @coreyman317 If you type the LHS minus the RHS into graphing software, you do not get zero everywhere; there are only a few points where it is zero. I don't think this identity holds. If this question is supposed to be an identity, either the teacher wrote it wrong or otherwise you have provided the wrong question.

Comment: @Kraig My mistake. Changing only one sign in OP’s given equation yields an identity however https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+%28sin%5E3%28x%29%2Bcos%5E3%28x%29%29%2F%281-2cos%5E2%28x%29%29%3D%28secx-sinx%29%2F%28tanx-1%29

Comment: @coreyman317 this might be why OP struggled so much; trying to solve an impossible identity isn't a great confidence boost

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. $\sec\theta = \dfrac1{\cos\theta}$
2. $\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)(\sin^2\theta - \sin\theta\cos\theta + \cos^2\theta)$
3. $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = ?$

Answer (score 0):

If you manipulate this equation as shown in the other answers, and continue from there, you can eventually show that $\cos\theta = 0,$ that is,
$\theta = \frac\pi2 + n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb Z.$

You can also cheat and enter the formula

$$ y = \frac{\sin^3 \theta + \cos^3 \theta}{1 - 2\cos^2 \theta} - \frac{\sec \theta -\sin \theta}{\tan\theta + 1}$$

into some convenient graphing software and observe where the zeros are.
(They appear to be at $\frac\pi2 + n\pi$ for integer $n.$)

But when $\cos\theta = 0,$ then $\sec\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are undefined, so the equation is not true.

I think this is a failure on the part of the author of the problem,
unless the objective was to find that the answer set is empty.

Comment: +1. You are right. This happens when one answers a question with such signs as they should be, not the original one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation can be simplified greatly, with the holes removed,

$$\frac{\sin^3 \theta + \cos^3 \theta}{1 - 2\cos^2 \theta} - \frac{\sec \theta -\sin \theta}{\tan\theta + 1} = -\cos\theta(2\sec2\theta-\tan2\theta)=0 $$

which leads to $\cos\theta = 0$ and the solutions

$$\theta = \frac\pi2+n\pi$$

The second factor $2\sec2\theta-\tan2\theta=0$ has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)^{3}+\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{3}}{1-2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{\sec\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)}{1+\tan\left(x\right)}$$

$$\frac{\left(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\right)\left(1-\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{1-2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{\cos\left(x\right)\left(1-\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)\left(\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)\right)}$$

if $\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\ne1 (x\ne2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{6},\ x\ne k\pi-\frac{\pi}{6})$ then:
$$\frac{\left(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{1-2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)\right)}$$

$$\left(\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{2}=1-2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)$$

$$1+2\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)=1-2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)$$
$$\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)=-\cos^{2}\left(x\right)$$

$$\cos\left(x\right)\left(\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)\right)=0$$

there are two cases:

either $\cos\left(x\right)=0$ or $\cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$

so $x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $x=k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}$

Also note that $x\ne-\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ since these $x$'s can make the denominator of the RHS $0$

hence finally $$x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$$

where $k∈ℤ$